# How do i get to collect static files ? i cant run this project it raises the error

Tags: python, django

Im running the command  python manage.py collectstatic

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /static
```

python manage.py collectstatic

```
This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
```

the error im gettting;
Can't open file "/static/fonts/FreeSans.ttf"

```
Copying '/home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/static/js/bootstrap.min.js'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 107, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 315, in copy_file
    self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 64, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 223, in _save
    os.makedirs(directory)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedir
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'
```

The error im gettting in the browser;

```
Can't open file "/static/fonts/FreeSans.ttf"
TTFError at /
Can't open file "/static/fonts/FreeSans.ttf"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: TTFError
Exception Value:    
Can't open file "/static/fonts/FreeSans.ttf"
```

Comment: sounds like a permission error... `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'` have you checked the permissions of the `static` folder?

Comment: Here it is, help me out                                                                              # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
try:
    from local_settings import *
except:
    pass

Comment: what i mean is the filesystem permission of the static folder, `ls -al /home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/static/`

Comment: Can you please edit it for me here is my code                                                                                                    STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/static‌​"), ) try: from local_settings import * except: pass

Answer (score 2):

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')` should be:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')`

The `/` resets tree and it looks for static dir in the root, i.e. literally: `/static` where you want to have something like `/home/user/project/static`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/') 
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( "/home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/static‌​", ) 
try: 
  from local_settings import * 
except: 
  pass
```

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is a place where you keep your own static files that should be collected with `collectstatic`. It cannot be the same as STATIC_ROOT.

Your structure with static can be like

```
DJANGO_PROJECT_DIR
|--> PROJECT_DIR
|----> settings.py
|----> templates
|----> static
|--> static
|--> manage.py
```

Then the code will be (replace PROJECT_DIR with your project dir name):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'PROJECT_DIR', 'static‌'), ) 
try: 
  from local_settings import * 
except: 
  pass
```

Comment: Can you please edit it for me here is my code                                       STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/static"),
)
try:
    from local_settings import *
except:
    pass

Comment: Use markdown for your code. I put the code into the answer (edit)

Comment: IM getting this error after the fix                                                             SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/ExportingFiles/settings.py on line 109, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: If you're using diacritic symbols like ę, ń, ó etc. you should declare utf-8 encoding at the start of settings.py: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. Or better way: remove special chars from strings.

Comment: error     "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

Comment: Did you use first or second code? Because it looks like you've set `/home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/static‌​` as your static_root too. And it cannot be the same. Check where you have your project static files and where is your manage.py dir. Can you sketch your project dir structure and put into question post? It would help a lot.

Comment: Hey should i use the first or second code in your answer

Comment: I suggest the second one, but be sure, your dir structure is such as noted above it.

Comment: can you just edit for the the correct path in the STATICFILES_DIRS in your second code

Comment: I cannot, since you didn't provide dir structure. Go see docs and change strings to fit your project: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: Is your manage.py file in `python-django-exporting-files` dir or `xls`?

Comment: Hey thanks,i managed to changed the project structure it worked and I ran manage.py collect static.. but then when i run the sever i get this error displayed in the browser .......TTFError at /
Can't open file "/home/mark/Desktop/xls/python-django-exporting-files/staticfonts/FreeSans.ttf"

Comment: OK, add "/" after static in STATIC_ROOT. My fault, sorry :) I edit answer according to this one. Usually it depends on how you do use statics in templates.