# Failing to load static CSS from Django on Azure

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, django-staticfiles

I followed [this tutorial from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database) and have this in my `settings.py`.

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/
```

However, after deploying my app, I find that the CSS file's request is canceled as seen in Chrome tools.

[image: canceled stylesheet]

I still get this error even after running:

```sh
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

which gives me files in `staticfiles` directory for `admin` and `app`. Note that I can run all this on `localhost` with no issue.

I tried the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970053/how-do-i-get-to-collect-static-files-i-cant-run-this-project-it-raises-the-err#answers-header) by switching from `/static/` to `static/` but ran into the same issue.

This is the directory structure I get when run `ls -la` on the Azure `az webapp ssh` immediately after running `python manage.py collectstatic`.

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root   4096 May 15 10:58 .
drwxrwxrwt 7 root root   4096 May 15 10:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 May 15 10:58 .azure
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2351 May 15 10:58 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    116 May 15 10:58 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 May 15 10:58 antenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 139264 May 15 10:58 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 May 15 10:58 project
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    665 May 15 10:58 manage.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    111 May 15 10:58 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 May 15 10:58 staticfiles
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root   4096 May 15 10:58 app
```

Given that I want to retain this structure of static files in their respective app directories and don't have CSS files that are not tied to any app, I don't have to use `STATICFILES_DIRS` as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/) says.

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (`STATICFILES_DIRS`) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files.

Comment: it may be a path problem. did you somehow try to print the STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: `which gives me files in staticfiles directory` which does not match shown config `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: `I can't use STATICFILES_DIRS` - not `can't` but `don't have to`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, I corrected the wording and the pasted code.

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu, how can I do that? I put print statements in my `settings.py` but didn't get any print out when I ran locally

Comment: settings.py is the config file it does not print anything. you can try to import the settings file to your views.py and then print settings.STATIC_ROOT. It may work.